# Using for loop to print out the data and their sums

Tags: java

I'm trying to print out the given set of numbers and their sum in the following way

[image]

and here is what I get:

[image]

and here is my code, please point out my mistake with some explanation. thank you!

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        addNums(1,2,3,4,5,6);
    }
    public static void addNums (int... nums) {
        String result = "";
        int sum=0;
        for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
            sum += i;
            result += i + " + ";
            for (int j = 0; j<i; j++) {
                String out = result.substring(0, result.length()-1) + " = " + sum;
                System.out.println(out);
            }
            System.out.println("");
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Does [this code](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38355422/4927984) solved your problem?

Answer (score 0):

I removed your second loop, and changed `result += i` by `result += nums[i]`:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        addNums(1,2,3,4,5,6);
    }

    public static void addNums (int... nums) {
        String result = "";
        int sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
            sum += nums[i];
            result += nums[i];
            if(i != nums.length) result += "+";
            String out = result.substring(0, result.length()-1) + " = " + sum;
            System.out.println(out);
        }
    }
```

It prints:

> 1 = 1
>
> 1+2 = 3
>
> 1+2+3 = 6
>
> 1+2+3+4 = 10
>
> 1+2+3+4+5 = 15
>
> 1+2+3+4+5+6 = 21

Comment: Updated, is that better?

Comment: It is :) Maybe this line `String out = result.substring(0, result.length()-1) + " = " + sum;` could also improved. I do not see the sense of using `substring`.

Answer (score 0):

And also, you are using the result of `i` instead of `nums[i]`.

`sum += nums[i];
result += nums[i] + " + ";`